# Accessibility issue on app registration page

Tags: bug, meta, design

#### Page containing bug

https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register

#### Reproduce the issue

Go to the page above. Whether you click on **Application Website** or **Application Icon**, it focuses the OAuth domain input.

#### Probable cause

This issue is caused by an improperly set `for` attribute on the `<label>` elements.

#### Suggested fix

Change the `for` attribute on each label. For example, for the label of **Application Website**, it should say `for="url"`, and for **Application Icon** it should say `for="image"`.